# The union of inverse elements of two algebraically independent sets

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

**Example:**
Let $A\cup B$ be algebraically independent over $\mathbb Q$. Consider
$$
S:=\{a^{-1}\colon a\in A\} \ \ \ \ \  D=\{b^{-1}\colon b\in B\}
$$
I know that $S$ and $D$ are algebraically independent. Is $S\cup D$ algebraically independent  or not ?

Answer (score 0):

$S\cup D=\{x^{-1}\,:\, x\in A\cup B\}$. Consider $s_1,\cdots, s_m$ distinct elements of $S\cup D$ and a polynomial $p\in \Bbb Q[T_1,\cdots, T_m]$ such that $p(s_1,\cdots, s_m)=0$. Then, $q(s_1^{-1},\cdots, s_m^{-1})=0$, where $q(T_1,\cdots, T_m):=(T_1\cdots T_m)^{\deg p}p(1/T_1,\cdots, 1/T_m)$.

Notice that, despite looking like a rational function, $q$ is actually the polynomial $$q(T_1,\cdots, T_m)=\sum_{h\in\{0,\cdots, \deg p\}^m}p_{h}T_1^{\deg p-h_1}\cdots T_m^{\deg p-h_m}$$

Since $s_1^{-1},\cdots, s_m^{-1}$ are distinct elements of $A\cup B$, it must be $q=0$ and, therefore, $p=0$.

The same works if you substitute $\Bbb Q$ with any field, and really the only hypothesis is that the you are considering the set of inverses of an algebraically independent subset.

Comment: Gae, S, Thank you very much for your answer. I have another question related to the above question, let $D\cup C$ be algebraically independent. How about $ S\cup D\cup C$? Is it algebraically independent ? I do not think it will be. Do you have an example?

Comment: Gae. S. I posted a question related to algebraically independent. I was wondering if you have an idea. Here is the question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4195659/707884. Thank you